# Heroku ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

First time posting on here. I've got a problem with my web-app when trying to open it through heroku. The app is successfully built by Heroku but when I try to open the app I get the following error:

```
2017-03-13T06:15:35.778714+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.778662 #4]  INFO -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 232ms (ActiveRecord: 18.7ms)
2017-03-13T06:15:35.779870+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.779817 #4] FATAL -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]   
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780386+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.779874 #4] FATAL -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780553+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.780501 #4] FATAL -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]      7:       <tr>    
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780554+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]      8:             <% row_cities.each do |city| %>     
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780555+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]      9:                 <td>
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780556+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]     10:                     <h3><%= city.name if city.name %></h3>
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780557+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]     11:                     <p><%= city.country %></p>
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780558+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]     12:                     <%= link_to "See More", city_path(city) %>
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780559+00:00 app[web.1]: [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]     13:                 </td>
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780602+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.780550 #4] FATAL -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964]   
2017-03-13T06:15:35.780655+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-13T06:15:35.780610 #4] FATAL -- : [773bef2b-dfb4-45a9-a15f-0de210ab6964] app/views/home_page/home.html.erb:10:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_home_page_home_html_erb__1188228438750051727_70102451451540'
```

Here is the problematic code (views: home.html.erb):

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <table>
    <% @cities.in_groups_of(3) do |row_cities| %>
        <tr>    
            <% row_cities.each do |city| %>     
                <td>
                    <h3><%= city.name %></h3>
                    <p><%= city.country %></p>
                    <%= link_to "See More", city_path(city) %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the controller this belongs to just in case (home_page_controller.rb):

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @cities = City.all
  end
end
```

I've been at this problems for two weeks now and have looked at other questions similar to this. I've tried all answers to no success. 
Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Llausa

P.S Here is how it looks on my localhost server and how I'd like it to look on heroku
[How I'd like it to look - image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww1PJ.png)

Comment: Run `heroku run console` and `City.all` inside it. Make sure each city has `.name` and not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Zulhilmi! What if I have 500+ cities? Do a City.where(name: nil) then delete?

Comment: Here name is not nil, City object is nil

Comment: There are no Cities where name is nil and City objects are present.

Comment: Have you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `in_group_of` with no option. Replace your code with this:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <table>
    <% @cities.in_groups_of(3,false) do |row_cities| %>
        <tr>    
            <% row_cities.each_with_index do |city,index| %>
                <td>
                    <h3><%= city.name %></h3>
                    <p><%= city.country %></p>
                    <%= link_to "See More", city_path(city) %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

[More info here](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of).

Comment: Dude, thanks sooo much!! Solved my problem with heroku. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help!